# socket option receive time out

Tags: c#

now lets take a secnario where we use a locking socket receive and the packet is 5000 bytes
with receivetimeout set to one second

```
s.SetSocketOption (SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 1000);

int bytes_recevied = 0 ;
byte [] ReceiveBuffer = new byte[8192] ;

try
{
   bytes_received = s.Receive(RecevieBuffer) ;
}
catch(SocketException e)
{
        if( e.ErrorCode == 10060)
        {
            Array.Clear(ReceiveBuffer,0,ReceiveBuffer.Length); 
        }
}
```

now our secnario dictates that 4000 bytes have gone threw alreadys,the socket is still blocking and some error accured on the receiving end ,
now on the receiving end we would handly dispose of the 4000 bytes by catching the socket ecxecption

is there any guaranty that the socket on the sending end wont thows 1000 bytes that remain
does the sending socket know to truncate them if he wasent disconnected when we attempt to receive again wont they be the first bytes we receive ?

what im asking is :
a) does tcp have some mecanisem that tells the socket to dispose of the rest of them message ?
b) is there a socket flag that we could send or receive with that tells the buffers to dispose of the rest of the message ?

Comment: Your code and most of your question don't make much sense. Probably because you misunderstood that TCP offers you only a stream and doesn't guarantee anything about packets.

Answer (score 1):

First off, [TCP/IP operates on streams, not packets](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/message-framing.html). So you need some kind of message framing in your protocol, regardless of buffer sizes, blocking calls, or MTUs.

Secondly, each TCP connection is independent. The normal design is to [close a socket](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/05/error-handling.html) when there's a communications error. A new socket connection can then be established, which is completely independent from the old one.